# OnsenUI with AngularJS Bootstrapping with Cordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui, monaca

I'm working on a Cordova application using AngularJS and OnsenUI. I'm having trouble with the documentation that's out there with respects to the call to ons.bootstrap().

Specifically, I am used to manually bootstrapping AngularJS applications in Cordova when needed -- i.e., either when the DOM loads, if I'm in a browser, or when the deviceready event fires, if I'm on a device, with a call to angular.bootstrap(document, [ 'myApp' ]).

I noticed that in Onsen, there's a necessary call to ons.bootstrap, with or without other parameters, such as ons.bootstrap('myApp', [...dependencies...]). I have fiddled around with this, and it seems like the only way I can get Onsen injected is if I use its bootstrapping call. However, elsewhere in my application's file, I'm still using the angular definitions (e.g., angular.module('myApp', [...dependencies...]).config(...).run(...)) and so forth.

I've found several things of questionable implementation, and haven't been able to find a definitive answer online as to this:

1) If I call angular.bootstrap within my initialization, Onsen never loads

2) If I use the ons.bootstrap call, things seem to work, but I end up repeating my dependencies within the bootstrapping call as well as my application definition using angular. This redundancy seems bad to me.

3) If I use both calls (not unexpectedly), I get a isWebView() already defined error, and the application goes nowhere.

Unfortunately, all of the examples on the Onsen website assumes all code (HTML, JS, etc.) like to reside in one spot, and doesn't seem to take Cordova into account. I've used Onsen in the past, but several versions ago, and the old methods of injection no longer seem to work.

So my question is, what is the way you're supposed to bootstrap and use Onsen, Angular, and Cordova together? Alternatively, is there a good example somewhere that *doesn't* involve Monaca?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there are good examples *somewhere*. Have you tried with the basic Onsen UI templates? They are provided in the 'Getting started' guide of Onsen UI and answer all your questions: http://onsen.io/download.html#download-templates

In short, Onsen UI is independent from Monaca and the only difference will be including Monaca's `loader.js` in your `index.html` (what includes OnsenUI, AngularJS, Cordova, etc.), or including all the libraries separately.
Also, `ons.bootstrap()` is optional, you can use `angular.module('app', ['onsen'])` if you want.

It is possible to use Cordova as well, you just need to include Cordova files as you would do in any other Cordova application. You can see it in the templates.

There are many examples out there with all of this, like the basic templates. More examples:

Onsen UI's Github: https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/tree/master/demo

Onsen UI's blog: http://onsen.io/blog/developing-hybrid-mobile-apps-with-onsen-ui/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for some reason, the only way I can get this thing to initialize appropriately is by using the Onsen bootstrap method and having it load all dependencies. Since `ons.bootstrap()` returns the Angular module, I'll use that for now.

So essentially, on the Cordova `deviceready` event, I call:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []);
angular.module('myApp.services', []);
ons.bootstrap('myApp', [ ...dependencies... ]);
```

And yes, there are plenty of examples out there, but the ones that incorporate Cordova and exercise a reasonable organizational facsimile of how actual code would be used, being that different objects are defined within different files, in multiple folders, are quite lacking. Although admittedly by Google-Fu isn't necessarily great.

Thank you for your response.